# Function on (closed) of <mat-expansion-panel> is called when I am opening the another panel

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2, angular2-directives

I am using the mat-accordion and inside this there is multiple mat-expansion-panel. On the very first mat-expansion-panel I am calling a function on (closed). By default very first mat-expansion-panel is closed.Now when the page loads and I am clicking on second mat-expansion-panel then the function of very first mat-expansion-panel (closed) is getting called(which should not be as it is not opened yet).

I want that when we open a expansion-panel and then close it or any other open any other expansion-panel then only the (closed) function of first expansion-panel will enter called.

```
<mat-accordion class="example-headers-align myaccordion">
             <mat-expansion-panel  hideToggle="true" class="myexpension" (opened)="fetchGeneralInfo()" (closed)="collpaseClose(0)"  #generalInfo>
             <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-title>
                            General Information
                </mat-panel-title>
 </mat-expansion-panel>

   <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle="true" class="myexpension" #guaInfo (opened)="fetchGua()" >
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Gurantor Information
      </mat-panel-title>
 </mat-expansion-panel>
```

Comment: This part, `collpaseClose(0)` looks like a potential culprit. You're always calling the method with the 0 index. You should use a variable to specify which expansion panel gets clicked instead.

Comment: HI @DanielB..Sorry for late response... But i am not calling with 0 every time. for each expansion panel I am having different index starting from 0.I am comparing the index in the TS file.

Answer (score 3):

Very late answer but I encountered the same issue.

Instead of `(opened)=...` use `(afterExpand)=...`.

Answer (score 2):

mat-accordion component has an input property **multi**.
@Input()multi: boolean :Whether the accordion should allow multiple expanded accordion items simultaneously.
As it is not set to true it may be triggering the closed event for other expansion panel.
Set **multi** to true `<mat-accordion [multi]="true">` and check.

Answer (score 0):

`<mat-expansion-panel #panel> </mat-expansion-panel>`

When you add the #panel reference to the mat-expansion-panel like this, you can unic control all the mat-expansion-panels you use. For example, you can check the status of the mat-expansion-panel with `panel.expanded` in this way, whether it is closed or open.